# How to add an extra button on woocommerce shop page and use it to send the product info with image in a mail?

Tags: customization, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, capabilities

I want an extra button beside "add to cart" which will open a form with only email field and after submitting, it will share product name, image, info with branding and backlink to the webpage in a proper format in a mail.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins (such as the one you have asked about) off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers may be slow if they come at all. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That said, I've also seen good answers on this topic so... (shrug)

Comment: The question wasn't for the plugin actually. It was just I was giving extra details. But now it I removed it.

Comment: Far be it for me to judge. I'm of the minority view that questions about third party stuff of sufficient note are probably fine most of the time.

Comment: can you please make me understand which part of the question is out off-topic? So that I will correct it.